# How deserialize the output from a QVariant without Qt

Tags: c++, string, qt, deserialization, qvariant

How Can I deserialize the output QVariant to std::string without using QT.

by reqs,  My program could not include a Qt.

`QVariant.toString().toStdString()`;

Example.

file.ini (write with QSetting)
..

```
ID="\x1\0\0\0\xd0\x8c\xd9\xec\xfb*"
```

profile_program /* Pseudo Code */

```
int main ()
{
   void* IDQt =getIDFromIniFile("file.ini");
   std::string myId = convertID(IDQt);
   process(myID);
}
```

Comment: How do you have a `QVariant` and then have the restriction of not being able to call its public members?

Comment: There a program that save data into a Ini file with QT. The data is record as "\x1\0\0\0\xd0\x8c\x9d\xdf\x1\x" so that I need to convert to char* to process them

Comment: To clarify you are wanting to deserialize the output from a QVariant in a project that does not include Qt. You have incorrectly worded your original question, I recommend you edit your post and add an example.

Comment: Using a proper clearly defined format for data exchange isn't possible? XML, JSon etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the sources, probably src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.cpp for `QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const QVariant&)`. That way you'll know what gets written during serialization.

Once you do, you'll see that the operator<< calls QVariant::save(QDataStream&). What's written is as follows:

```
quint32 QVariant::type()
quint8 QVariant::isNull()
if type()==UserType
  QString MetaType::typeName(userType())
end
if the variant is not valid
  QString empty
else
  -- MetaType::save(...)
end
```

You need to drill down into QString and QMetaType to figure out how those are serialized.